# Optimize query with subquery and join

Tags: mysql, sql

My query

```
SELECT a.* FROM hm_all a 
JOIN ( SELECT post_id, MIN(priceUS_USD) as price FROM hm_all GROUP BY post_id ) b 
ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND a.priceUS_USD = b.price 
ORDER BY a.post_id ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

Explain

```
id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
1    PRIMARY       a            index    post_id         post_id  4         NULL   1      Using where
1    PRIMARY       <derived2>   ref      key0            key0     9         a.po.  10
2    DERIVED       hm_all       index    NULL            post_id  4         NULL   12112
```

The query works fine but slow. I wonder how to speed up?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Presumably you already tried a covering index on `(post_id,price)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from hm_all a
where a.priceUS_USD = (select min(a2.priceUS_USD) 
                       from hm_all a2
                       where a2.post_id = a.post_id
                      )
order by a.post_id
limit 20;
```

Then for performance you want an index on `hm_all(post_id, priceUS_USD)`.

Comment: @TomHarisond Note that it's the index that makes the difference - and not the choice of a correlated query vs a non-corellated one.

Comment: @Strawberry In this case, the index helped a little, but not much. Changing the query helped a lot.

Comment: @TomHarisond I suspect that that depends on the cardinality/density of your post_ids. On a sparse data set (lots of different post_ids, with few repetitions), I think this would be faster. On a dense data set (fewer different post_ids, but lots of each), I think your query (with the same index) would be more performant.

Comment: Indeed, but doesn't this answer rather make the opposite assumption (which, in fairness, turned out to be the correct one)?